# Question on Method of Characteristics & Characteristic Curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE

$$
\begin{align}
u_t + (vu)_x &= 0,\phantom{u_0(x)} \quad x \in \mathbb{R},\, t>0 \\
u(x,0)&=u_0(x),\phantom{0} \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

Let $s \to z(s,x,t)$ be the characteristic curve passing through $(x,t)$; that is, $z(s,x,t)$ is the solution to the ODE

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z}(s) &= v(z(s),s) \\
z(t) &= x
\end{align}
$$

My question is, does the set $\left\{z(0,x,t) : x \in \mathbb{R},\, t>0\right\}$ cover the whole of $\mathbb{R}$? And if so, why? Clearly the set $\left\{z(t,x,t) : x \in \mathbb{R},\, t>0\right\}$ does since $z(t)=x$ by definition.

The reason I ask is that I have shown $|u(x,t)| \leq |u_0(z(0,x,t))|$, and I want to conclude that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|u(x,t)| \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|u_0(x)|$. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Z_t:=\{z(0,x,t)\ |\ x\in\mathbb R\}$. Then by what you have already shown it follows that for fixed $t>0$:
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|u(x,t)|\leq\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|u_0(z(0,x,t))|=\sup_{x\in Z_t}|u_0(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|u_0(x)|,
\end{align*}
so you don't need that $\bigcup_{t>0}Z_t=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh. Yes indeed, that was rather silly of me. Thanks! 

I guess the answer to my original question (for interest's sake) isn't 'yes' in general...